# For what does AppleTV have micro-USB port?

Tags: usb, appletv

I noticed that AppleTV has a micro USB port. How and why will one use it ?

Answer (score 2):

Service & diagnostics, recovery etc.

See [Restoring your Apple TV](http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT4367)